# Cant uploading an image into the server using upload script

Tags: upload, photo

Sir 
  this a part of our mini project and the code use to work well without the option to upload an image.Here we are having a folder "missingCaseImage" inorder to stre the uploaded image. But this code shows that the image already exist while pressing procced button

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC >
   <?php 
    include("connection.php"); 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['proceed']))
     {

       $ctype=$_POST['id13'];
       $email=$_POST['email'];
          if($ctype=='Missing'){
          $MCImage=$_FILES['missingImage']["name"];
      if (file_exists("../missingCaseImage/" . $MCImage))
            {
      ?>
                <script>
        alert('Image Name already exists');
        window.location.href='dem.php';
        </script>
             <?php
      exit;
              }
         else
          {
           move_uploaded_file($_FILES["missingImage"]["tmp_name"],"../missingCaseImage/" .       
           $_FILES["missingImage"]["name"]);
           }

          }

 $insert="insert into cregister(e_mail,image,cs_type,) values('$email','$MCImage')";
 mysql_query($insert);
 $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
 $_SESSION['cno']=$lastid;
 header("location:printform.php"); 
 }

   ?>

 <html >

 <?php
  if(isset($_GET['error'])){$error=$_GET['error'];} else{$error="";} // if error happaning echo this $error msg
 ?>
 <fieldset>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<h3>CASE REGISTRATION FORM</h3>  

<P>
 <label for="id1">EMAIL ID</label>
 <input name="email" type="email" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" id="email" value="<?php echo    $_SESSION['email'];?>" 
 readonly/>
 <br />
 <P> 
  <label for="id1">CASE TYPE</label>


  <select name="id13" class="validate[required]" id="id13" onChange="missingCase(this.value)">
  <option>Murder</option>
  <option>Robbery</option>
  <option>Vehicle</option>
  <option>Missing</option>
  <option>Others</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <P style="display:none;" id="missingImageP" > 
  <label for="missingImage">UPLOAD IMAGE</label>
  <input type="file" name="missingImage" class="uploadMC"/>
  <p>
  <input name="proceed" type="submit" id="proceed" value="PROCEED"? />
  <p>
  </form>
  </fieldset>
  </html>

 <script>
  function missingCase(mc){ 
//alert(mc);
if(mc=='Missing'){
    $('#missingImageP').show();
    }
else{
        $('#missingImageP').hide();
    }

  }
  </script>
```

So now the problem is whenever i try to upload a photo and click on proceed button it always displays Image Name already exists... Why is that so how can i rectify it

NOte: All the required script for validation were been included ..

Thankyou in advance...

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question. It is finding an image with the same name as the one you're trying to upload.

Comment: no the folder is empty still it shows the same!!